# Creating dynamic variable name for Threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new to Python development. My requirement is this:

I have an undefined number of processes to run. I am supposed to pick three at a time and add them to queue and process them. Once the three are completed, I need to process the next three and so on. This is the snippet which captures this logic:

```
for i in range(numOfPools):
    for j in range(3):
        if Conditions:
            pool.add_task(self.method,parameter)
    pool.wait_completion
```

where pool is a Queue of threads. add_task and wait_completion methods are used to put task in the thread and join the three threads respectively.

This code seems to be working fine. However, if there are large number of pools created this way, will having the same name for all the Queues affect the execution of the program? I checked on creating unique variable names dynamically but I found that is is generally discouraged in Python. Can anyone provide me with a solution to this?

Thanks,

Keerthana

Comment: What about using a `list` or a `dict` to hold multiple pools...!? A solution you surely must have stumbled upon in researching this...

Comment: You mean like a list of queue of threads?

Comment: @Keerthana just a list of thread. If you are already using queue means you could dequeue from that